# error: use of deleted function ‘Luta::Luta()’

Tags: c++, classes, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Boa tarde, eu estou tento varios problemas ao compilar o código abaixo no code::blocks com g++ e eu gostaria de obter ajuda, desde já agradeço.

Conteúdo do main.cpp:

```
#include "Lutador.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    Lutador *Pretty_Boy=new Lutador("Pretty  Boy","França",11,2,1,31,1.75,68.9);
    Lutador *Putscript=new Lutador("Putscript","Brasil",14,2,3,29,1.68,57.8);
    Lutador *Snapshadow=new Lutador("Snapshadow","EUA",12,2,1,35,1.65,80.9);
    Lutador *Deat_Code=new Lutador("Dead Code","Austrália",13,0,2,28,1.93,81.6);
    Lutador *Ufocobol=new  Lutador("Ufocobol","Brasil",5,4,3,37,1.70,119.3);;
    Lutador *Nerdaard=new Lutador("Nerdaard","EUA",12,2,4,30,1.81,105.7);

    Luta *UEC01=new Luta;

    UEC01->MarcarLuta(*Pretty_Boy, *Putscript);

    return 0;
}
```

Conteúdo da classe Lutador.h

```
#ifndef LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED
#define LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Lutador{
    private:
        std::string nome;
        std::string nacionalidade;
        std::string categoria; //peso leve, peso médio, peso pesado
        short vitorias;
        short derrotas;
        short empates;
        short idade;
        float altura;
        float peso;
    public:
        std::string getNome();
        std::string getNacionalidade();
        std::string getCategoria();
        short getVitorias();
        short getDerrotas();
        short getEmpates();
        short getIdade();
        float getAltura();
        float getPeso();
    public:
        void setNome(std::string nome);
        void setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade);
        void setVitorias(short vitorias);
        void setDerrotas(short derrotas);
        void setEmpates(short empates);
        void setIdade(short idade);
        void setAltura(float altura);
        void setPeso(float peso);
    public:
        void apresenta();
        void status();
        void ganharLuta();
        void perderLuta();
        void empatarLuta();
    public:
        Lutador(std::string nome, std::string nacionalidade, short vitorias, short derrotas,short empates,short idade, float altura, float peso);
};

#endif // LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED
```

Conteúdo da classe Luta.h

```
#ifndef LUTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LUTA_H_INCLUDED

#include "Lutador.h"

class Luta{
    private:
        Lutador Desafiado;
        Lutador Desafiante;
        short rounds;
        bool aprovada;
    public:
        Lutador getDesafiado();
        Lutador getDesafiante();
        short getRounds();
        bool getAprovada();
    public:
        void setDesafiado(Lutador DO);
        void setDesafiante(Lutador DE);
        void setRounds(short num_rounds);
        void setAprovada(short YN);
    public:
        void MarcarLuta(Lutador L1, Lutador L2);
        void lutar();

};

#endif // LUTA_H_INCLUDED
```

Conteúdo do arquivo Lutador.cpp

```
#include "Lutador.h"
#include "Luta.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string Lutador::getNome(){
    return nome;
}
std::string Lutador::getNacionalidade(){
    return nacionalidade;
}
std::string Lutador::getCategoria(){
    return categoria;
}
short Lutador::getVitorias(){
    return vitorias;
}
short Lutador::getDerrotas(){
    return derrotas;
}
short Lutador::getEmpates(){
    return empates;
}
short Lutador::getIdade(){
    return idade;
}
float Lutador::getAltura(){
    return altura;
}
float Lutador::getPeso(){
    return peso;
}

void Lutador::setNome(std::string nome){
    this->nome=nome;
}
void Lutador::setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade){
    this->nacionalidade=nacionalidade;
}
void Lutador::setVitorias(short vitorias){
    this->vitorias=vitorias;
}
void Lutador::setDerrotas(short derrotas){
    this->derrotas=derrotas;
}
void Lutador::setEmpates(short empates){
    this->empates=empates;
}
void Lutador::setIdade(short idade){
    this->idade=idade;
}
void Lutador::setAltura(float altura){
    this->altura=altura;
}
void Lutador::setPeso(float peso){
    this->peso=peso;
}

void Lutador::apresenta(){
    std::cout << "Nome.............: " << getNome() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Nacionalidade....: " << getNacionalidade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Categoria........: " << getCategoria() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vitorias.........: " << getVitorias() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Derrotas.........: " << getDerrotas() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Empates..........: " << getEmpates() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Idade............: " << getIdade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Altura...........: " << getAltura() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Peso.............: " << getPeso() << "\n\n\n";
}

void Lutador::status(){
     std::cout << getNome() << "\n";
     std::cout << getVitorias() << "\n";
     std::cout << getEmpates() << "\n";
     std::cout << getDerrotas() << "\n";
}
void Lutador::ganharLuta(){
     setVitorias(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::perderLuta(){
     setDerrotas(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::empatarLuta(){
     setEmpates(getEmpates()+1);
}

 Lutador::Lutador(std::string no, std::string na, short vi, short de,short    em,short id, float al, float pe){

    setNome(no);
    setNacionalidade(na);
    setVitorias(vi);
    setDerrotas(de);
    setEmpates(em);
    setIdade(id);
    setAltura(al);
    setPeso(pe);

    if(peso<=80){
        categoria="Peso Leve";
    }else if(peso<=110){
        categoria="Peso medio";
    }else if(peso>110){
        categoria="Peso pesado";
    }
}
```

Conteúdo do arquivo Luta.cpp

```
#include "Luta.h"
#include <iostream>

Lutador Luta::getDesafiado(){
    return Desafiado;
}
Lutador Luta::getDesafiante(){
    return Desafiante;
}
short Luta::getRounds(){
    return rounds;
}
bool Luta::getAprovada(){
    return aprovada;
}

void Luta::setDesafiado(Lutador DO){
    Desafiado=DO;
}
void Luta::setDesafiante(Lutador DE){
    Desafiante=DE;
}
void Luta::setRounds(short num_rounds){
    rounds=num_rounds;
}
void Luta::setAprovada(short YN){
    aprovada=YN;

if(aprovada==1){
    std::cout << "Luta aprovada\n";
    lutar();
}else{
        std::cout << "Luta não aprovada\n";
   }
}

void Luta::MarcarLuta(Lutador L1, Lutador L2){
    if(L1.getCategoria()!=L2.getCategoria() &&   L1.getNome()!=L2.getNome()){
    setAprovada(0);
    }else{
        setAprovada(1);
        setDesafiado(L1);
        setDesafiante(L2);
    }
}
void Luta::lutar(){
    if(getAprovada()==1){
        Desafiado.apresenta();
        Desafiante.apresenta();
    }else{
        std::cout << "Impossivel realizar a luta\n\n";
    }

    short vencedor=rand()%700;

    if(vencedor<=200){
        Desafiado.empatarLuta();
        Desafiante.empatarLuta();
    }else if(vencedor<=400){
        Desafiado.ganharLuta();
        Desafiante.perderLuta();
    }else if(vencedor<=600){
        Desafiado.perderLuta();
        Desafiante.ganharLuta();
    }
}
```

Os erros retornados na compilação são estes:

> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/main.cpp|14|error: use of
>   deleted function ‘Luta::Luta()’|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Luta.h|6|note:
>   ‘Luta::Luta()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition
>   would be ill-formed:|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Luta.h|6|error: no
>   matching function for call to ‘Lutador::Lutador()’|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.cpp|87|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(std::__cxx11::string,
>   std::__cxx11::string, short int, short int, short int, short int,
>   float, float)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.cpp|87|note:
>   candidate expects 8 arguments, 0 provided|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(const Lutador&)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(Lutador&&)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Luta.h|6|error: no
>   matching function for call to ‘Lutador::Lutador()’|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.cpp|87|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(std::__cxx11::string,
>   std::__cxx11::string, short int, short int, short int, short int,
>   float, float)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.cpp|87|note:
>   candidate expects 8 arguments, 0 provided|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(const Lutador&)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate: Lutador::Lutador(Lutador&&)|
>
> /home/Khyser/Documentos/Curso de POO/Aula 07/Lutador.h|6|note:
>   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ser possível a passagem do objeto `Lutador` por valor é necessário a implementação correta da "[Regra dos Três](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))".

Wikipedia:

> Uma regra informal no desenvolvimento orientado a objeto em C++ clama
>   que se uma classe ou estrutura possui um dos seguintes itens, ela
>   provavelmente deveria ter todos os três: `Destrutor`, `construtor de cópia` e `operador de atribuição` `(=)`.
>
> Esses três métodos são funções membros especiais criadas pelo
>   compilador automaticamente se não são definidas pelo
>   desenvolvedor. Se um desses métodos é definido explicitamente
>   pelo desenvolvedor, isso significa que a versão gerada pelo compilador
>   não serve para um dos casos, e portanto muito provavelmente também não
>   serve para os outros casos.

Segue uma possivel solução (testada) com a implmentação da regra na classe `Lutador` e da inclusão de um `construtor padrão` na classe `Luta`:

`Lutador.h`

```
#ifndef LUTADOR_H
#define LUTADOR_H

#include <string>

class Lutador
{
    public:

        Lutador( void );
        Lutador( std::string nome, std::string nacionalidade, short vitorias, short derrotas, short empates, short idade, float altura, float peso);
        Lutador( const Lutador & obj );
        virtual ~Lutador( void );
        Lutador& operator=( const Lutador & obj );
        bool operator==( Lutador &obj );

    private:

        std::string nome;
        std::string nacionalidade;
        short vitorias;
        short derrotas;
        short empates;
        short idade;
        float altura;
        float peso;

    public:

        std::string getNome();
        std::string getNacionalidade();
        std::string getCategoria();
        short getVitorias();
        short getDerrotas();
        short getEmpates();
        short getIdade();
        float getAltura();
        float getPeso();

    public:

        void setNome(std::string nome);
        void setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade);
        void setVitorias(short vitorias);
        void setDerrotas(short derrotas);
        void setEmpates(short empates);
        void setIdade(short idade);
        void setAltura(float altura);
        void setPeso(float peso);

    public:

        void apresenta();
        void status();
        void ganharLuta();
        void perderLuta();
        void empatarLuta();
};

#endif
```

`Luta.h`

```
#ifndef LUTA_H
#define LUTA_H

#include "Lutador.h"

class Luta
{
    public:

        Luta();
        virtual ~Luta();

    private:

        Lutador Desafiado;
        Lutador Desafiante;
        short rounds;
        bool aprovada;

    public:

        Lutador getDesafiado();
        Lutador getDesafiante();
        short getRounds();
        bool getAprovada();

    public:

        void setDesafiado(Lutador DO);
        void setDesafiante(Lutador DE);
        void setRounds(short num_rounds);
        void setAprovada(short YN);

    public:

        void MarcarLuta(Lutador L1, Lutador L2);
        void lutar();

};

#endif
```

`Lutador.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Lutador.h"
#include "Luta.h"

Lutador::Lutador(void) :
    nome(""),
    nacionalidade(""),
    vitorias(0),
    derrotas(0),
    empates(0),
    idade(0),
    altura(0),
    peso(0)
{
}

Lutador::Lutador( const Lutador & obj ) :
    nome(obj.nome),
    nacionalidade(obj.nacionalidade),
    vitorias(obj.vitorias),
    derrotas(obj.derrotas),
    empates(obj.empates),
    idade(obj.idade),
    altura(obj.altura),
    peso(obj.peso)
{
}

Lutador& Lutador::operator=( const Lutador & obj ){
    this->nome = obj.nome;
    this->nacionalidade = obj.nacionalidade;
    this->vitorias = obj.vitorias;
    this->derrotas = obj.derrotas;
    this->empates = obj.empates;
    this->idade = obj.idade;
    this->altura = obj.altura;
    this->peso = obj.peso;
    return *this;
}

bool Lutador::operator==( Lutador &obj ) {
    return ((this->nome != obj.nome) && (this->getCategoria() != obj.getCategoria()));
}

Lutador::~Lutador(void)
{
}

Lutador::Lutador(std::string no, std::string na, short vi, short de,short em,short id, float al, float pe) :
    nome(no),
    nacionalidade(na),
    vitorias(vi),
    derrotas(de),
    empates(em),
    idade(id),
    altura(al),
    peso(pe)
{
}
std::string Lutador::getNome(){
    return nome;
}
std::string Lutador::getNacionalidade(){
    return nacionalidade;
}
std::string Lutador::getCategoria(){
    if(peso<=80){
        return "Peso Leve";
    }else if(peso<=110){
        return "Peso medio";
    }
    else {
        return "Peso pesado";
    }
}
short Lutador::getVitorias(){
    return vitorias;
}
short Lutador::getDerrotas(){
    return derrotas;
}
short Lutador::getEmpates(){
    return empates;
}
short Lutador::getIdade(){
    return idade;
}
float Lutador::getAltura(){
    return altura;
}
float Lutador::getPeso(){
    return peso;
}

void Lutador::setNome(std::string nome){
    this->nome=nome;
}
void Lutador::setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade){
    this->nacionalidade=nacionalidade;
}
void Lutador::setVitorias(short vitorias){
    this->vitorias=vitorias;
}
void Lutador::setDerrotas(short derrotas){
    this->derrotas=derrotas;
}
void Lutador::setEmpates(short empates){
    this->empates=empates;
}
void Lutador::setIdade(short idade){
    this->idade=idade;
}
void Lutador::setAltura(float altura){
    this->altura=altura;
}
void Lutador::setPeso(float peso){
    this->peso=peso;
}

void Lutador::apresenta(){
    std::cout << "Nome.............: " << getNome() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Nacionalidade....: " << getNacionalidade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Categoria........: " << getCategoria() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vitorias.........: " << getVitorias() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Derrotas.........: " << getDerrotas() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Empates..........: " << getEmpates() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Idade............: " << getIdade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Altura...........: " << getAltura() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Peso.............: " << getPeso() << "\n\n\n";
}

void Lutador::status(){
     std::cout << getNome() << "\n";
     std::cout << getVitorias() << "\n";
     std::cout << getEmpates() << "\n";
     std::cout << getDerrotas() << "\n";
}
void Lutador::ganharLuta(){
     setVitorias(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::perderLuta(){
     setDerrotas(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::empatarLuta(){
     setEmpates(getEmpates()+1);
}
```

`Luta.cpp`

```
#include "Luta.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

Luta::Luta(){
}

Luta::~Luta(){
}

Lutador Luta::getDesafiado(){
    return Desafiado;
}
Lutador Luta::getDesafiante(){
    return Desafiante;
}
short Luta::getRounds(){
    return rounds;
}
bool Luta::getAprovada(){
    return aprovada;
}

void Luta::setDesafiado(Lutador DO){
    Desafiado=DO;
}
void Luta::setDesafiante(Lutador DE){
    Desafiante=DE;
}
void Luta::setRounds(short num_rounds){
    rounds=num_rounds;
}
void Luta::setAprovada(short YN){
    aprovada=YN;
    if(aprovada==1){
        std::cout << "Luta aprovada\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "Luta não aprovada\n";
    }
}

void Luta::MarcarLuta(Lutador L1, Lutador L2){
    if( L1 == L2 ){
        setAprovada(0);
    }else{
        setAprovada(1);
        setDesafiado(L1);
        setDesafiante(L2);
    }
}
void Luta::lutar(){
    if(getAprovada()==1){
        Desafiado.apresenta();
        Desafiante.apresenta();
    }else{
        std::cout << "Impossivel realizar a luta\n\n";
    }

    short vencedor=rand()%700;

    if(vencedor<=200){
        Desafiado.empatarLuta();
        Desafiante.empatarLuta();
    }else if(vencedor<=400){
        Desafiado.ganharLuta();
        Desafiante.perderLuta();
    }else if(vencedor<=600){
        Desafiado.perderLuta();
        Desafiante.ganharLuta();
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Lutador.h"
#include "Luta.h"

int main( void ){

    Lutador Pretty_Boy("Pretty Boy","França",11,2,1,31,1.75,68.9);
    Lutador Putscript("Putscript","Brasil",14,2,3,29,1.68,57.8);
    Lutador Snapshadow("Snapshadow","EUA",12,2,1,35,1.65,80.9);
    Lutador Deat_Code("Dead Code","Austrália",13,0,2,28,1.93,81.6);
    Lutador Ufocobol("Ufocobol","Brasil",5,4,3,37,1.70,119.3);
    Lutador Nerdaard("Nerdaard","EUA",12,2,4,30,1.81,105.7);

    Luta UEC01;

    UEC01.MarcarLuta( Pretty_Boy, Putscript );

    UEC01.lutar();

   return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./luta 
Luta aprovada
Nome.............: Pretty Boy
Nacionalidade....: França
Categoria........: Peso Leve
Vitorias.........: 11
Derrotas.........: 2
Empates..........: 1
Idade............: 31
Altura...........: 1.75
Peso.............: 68.9


Nome.............: Putscript
Nacionalidade....: Brasil
Categoria........: Peso Leve
Vitorias.........: 14
Derrotas.........: 2
Empates..........: 3
Idade............: 29
Altura...........: 1.68
Peso.............: 57.8
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que mudou e como funciona sua abordagem? Acho que seria muito útil para a comunidade.

Comment: Minha abordagem simplemente implementa a "regra dos três", algo que o código original da pergunta simplemente ignora. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Regra_dos_tr.C3.AAs

Comment: Isso eu já entendi, o intuito é explicar o que fez no código, mas tudo bem não é obrigação, é dica apenas, afinal quem chega no site esta aprendendo ainda, explicar as mudanças ajudam, mas não é tão necessário. Até.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Segue edição

Answer (score 0):

Ok, vamos por partes. Geralmente não se inclui o .cpp no main. Você colocou corretamente o include guard nas *headers* (.h), porém não no .cpp, o que causava redefinição das funções. E disse que UEC01 = new Luta. Perceba que você não chamou um construtor (Luta();), o que também causava erro.

Teu main fica assim:

```
#include "Lutador.h"
#include "Luta.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    Lutador *Pretty_Boy=new Lutador("Pretty  Boy","França",11,2,1,31,1.75,68.9);
    Lutador *Putscript=new Lutador("Putscript","Brasil",14,2,3,29,1.68,57.8);
    Lutador *Snapshadow=new Lutador("Snapshadow","EUA",12,2,1,35,1.65,80.9);
    Lutador *Deat_Code=new Lutador("Dead Code","Austrália",13,0,2,28,1.93,81.6);
    Lutador *Ufocobol=new  Lutador("Ufocobol","Brasil",5,4,3,37,1.70,119.3);;
    Lutador *Nerdaard=new Lutador("Nerdaard","EUA",12,2,4,30,1.81,105.7);

    Luta *UEC01 = new Luta();

    UEC01->MarcarLuta(Pretty_Boy, Putscript);

    return 0;
}
```

Mudei um pouco teu código para ele ficar mais dinâmico. Outro erro fatal foi na função MarcarLuta(), o setAprovado fazia com que o programa fosse para a luta() antes de setar os desafiantes, o que dava segfault. Sõ inverti a ordem ali:

Teu Lutador.h:

```
#ifndef LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED
#define LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Lutador{
    private:
        std::string nome;
        std::string nacionalidade;
        std::string categoria; //peso leve, peso médio, peso pesado
        short vitorias;
        short derrotas;
        short empates;
        short idade;
        float altura;
        float peso;
    public:
        std::string getNome();
        std::string getNacionalidade();
        std::string getCategoria();
        short getVitorias();
        short getDerrotas();
        short getEmpates();
        short getIdade();
        float getAltura();
        float getPeso();
    public:
        void setNome(std::string nome);
        void setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade);
        void setVitorias(short vitorias);
        void setDerrotas(short derrotas);
        void setEmpates(short empates);
        void setIdade(short idade);
        void setAltura(float altura);
        void setPeso(float peso);
    public:
        void apresenta();
        void status();
        void ganharLuta();
        void perderLuta();
        void empatarLuta();
    public:
        Lutador(std::string nome, std::string nacionalidade, short vitorias, short derrotas,short empates,short idade, float altura, float peso);
};

#endif // LUTADOR_H_INCLUDED
```

Teu Luta.h:

```
#ifndef LUTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LUTA_H_INCLUDED

#include "Lutador.h"

    class Luta{
        private:
            Lutador *Desafiado;
            Lutador *Desafiante;
            short rounds;
            bool aprovada;
        public:
            Lutador *getDesafiado();
            Lutador *getDesafiante();
            short getRounds();
            bool getAprovada();
        public:
            void setDesafiado(Lutador *DO);
            void setDesafiante(Lutador *DE);
            void setRounds(short num_rounds);
            void setAprovada(short YN);
        public:
            void MarcarLuta(Lutador *L1, Lutador *L2);
            void lutar();

    };

    #endif // LUTA_H_INCLUDED
```

Teu Lutador.cpp

```
#include "Lutador.h"
#include "Luta.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



std::string Lutador::getNome(){
    return nome;
}
std::string Lutador::getNacionalidade(){
    return nacionalidade;
}
std::string Lutador::getCategoria(){
    return categoria;
}
short Lutador::getVitorias(){
    return vitorias;
}
short Lutador::getDerrotas(){
    return derrotas;
}
short Lutador::getEmpates(){
    return empates;
}
short Lutador::getIdade(){
    return idade;
}
float Lutador::getAltura(){
    return altura;
}
float Lutador::getPeso(){
    return peso;
}

void Lutador::setNome(std::string nome){
    this->nome=nome;
}
void Lutador::setNacionalidade(std::string nacionalidade){
    this->nacionalidade=nacionalidade;
}
void Lutador::setVitorias(short vitorias){
    this->vitorias=vitorias;
}
void Lutador::setDerrotas(short derrotas){
    this->derrotas=derrotas;
}
void Lutador::setEmpates(short empates){
    this->empates=empates;
}
void Lutador::setIdade(short idade){
    this->idade=idade;
}
void Lutador::setAltura(float altura){
    this->altura=altura;
}
void Lutador::setPeso(float peso){
    this->peso=peso;
}

void Lutador::apresenta(){
    std::cout << "Nome.............: " << this->getNome() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Nacionalidade....: " << this->getNacionalidade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Categoria........: " << this->getCategoria() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Vitorias.........: " << this->getVitorias() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Derrotas.........: " << this->getDerrotas() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Empates..........: " << this->getEmpates() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Idade............: " << this->getIdade() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Altura...........: " << this->getAltura() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Peso.............: " << this->getPeso() << "\n\n\n";
}

void Lutador::status(){
     std::cout << getNome() << "\n";
     std::cout << getVitorias() << "\n";
     std::cout << getEmpates() << "\n";
     std::cout << getDerrotas() << "\n";
}
void Lutador::ganharLuta(){
     setVitorias(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::perderLuta(){
     setDerrotas(getVitorias()+1);
}
void Lutador::empatarLuta(){
     setEmpates(getEmpates()+1);
}

 Lutador::Lutador(std::string no, std::string na, short vi, short de,short    em,short id, float al, float pe){

    setNome(no);
    setNacionalidade(na);
    setVitorias(vi);
    setDerrotas(de);
    setEmpates(em);
    setIdade(id);
    setAltura(al);
    setPeso(pe);

    if(peso<=80){
        categoria="Peso Leve";
    }else if(peso<=110){
        categoria="Peso medio";
    }else if(peso>110){
        categoria="Peso pesado";
    }
}
```

Teu Luta.cpp

```
#include "Luta.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Lutador.h"


Lutador* Luta::getDesafiado(){
    return Desafiado;
}
Lutador *Luta::getDesafiante(){
    return Desafiante;
}
short Luta::getRounds(){
    return rounds;
}
bool Luta::getAprovada(){
    return aprovada;
}

void Luta::setDesafiado(Lutador *DO){
    this->Desafiado = DO;
}
void Luta::setDesafiante(Lutador *DE){
    Desafiante=DE;
}
void Luta::setRounds(short num_rounds){
    rounds=num_rounds;
}
void Luta::setAprovada(short YN){
    aprovada=YN;

if(aprovada==1){
    std::cout << "Luta aprovada\n";
    lutar();
}else{
        std::cout << "Luta não aprovada\n";
   }
}

void Luta::MarcarLuta(Lutador *L1, Lutador *L2){
    if(L1->getCategoria()!=L2->getCategoria() &&   L1->getNome()!=L2->getNome()){
    setAprovada(0);
    }else{
        setDesafiado(L1);
        setDesafiante(L2);
        setAprovada(1);
    }
}
void Luta::lutar(){
    if(getAprovada()==1){
        Desafiado->apresenta();
        Desafiante->apresenta();
    }else{
        std::cout << "Impossivel realizar a luta\n\n";
    }

    short vencedor=rand()%700;

    if(vencedor<=200){
    Desafiado->empatarLuta();
    Desafiante->empatarLuta();
}else if(vencedor<=400){
    Desafiado->ganharLuta();
    Desafiante->perderLuta();
}else if(vencedor<=600){
    Desafiado->perderLuta();
    Desafiante->ganharLuta();
}
}
```

Comment: Apesar das modificações ainda continua retornando os mesmos erros...